# calling multiple functions onclick of radio button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I was reading topic on calling multiple functions using onclick eventhandler on radio buttons.
After reading the comments I am more confused than ever. 
I have two questions.
1. Is it possible to call more than one function with the onclick event handler?
2. If it is possible are the functions performed sequentially or simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) yes its possible to call multiple function in onclick event handler

(2) calls will be made sequentially

```
But: script tag containing function must loaded before onclick defined tags
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/8R4zm/5/

Comment: so if i have external script refrenced in head section and onclick in body section on individual form elements. It should work ?

Comment: yes it should work, 
one more thing :: the function you are calling should be global.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can perform two events for single click like below

```
onClick="doSomething();doSomethingElse();"
```

or you can perform like this

```
<a onclick="someFunc()">Calling Multiple Functions</a>


function someFunc()
 {
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
    doSomethingElse();
    .
    .
    . 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can attach many event handler functions for an event using addEventListener. But there is no guarantee it will be executed in the order in which you add.

Eg.

```
element.addEventListener('click',markForCancel,false)
element.addEventListener('click',logCancelledRows,false)
```